# How to set start application animation?

Tags: android, animation, startup

I am trying to find the simplest way to show an image on entrance to application right before the activity starts. How do I do it in the simplest way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look into this tutorial:
http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Creating_a_Splash_Screen
[http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right](http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/)